# Dynamically change iframe height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe that loads content and gets the size of the pages content when loaded. The page source is an angular app, so as you move through the pages, the pages height changes (but the page doesn't actually refresh to get the data).

What is the best way to change the size of the div, based on the different content on each angular page?

Some have suggested a timer, checking every 'x' seconds - if so how would I do that? if not what is best practice.

I am using the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function iframeLoaded() {
      var iFrameID = document.getElementById('idIframe');
      if(iFrameID) {
            // here you can make the height, I delete it first, then I make it again
            iFrameID.height = "";
            iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
      }   
  }
</script>
```

and the iframe looks like this

```
<iframe id="idIframe" onload="iframeLoaded()" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Timer is not a good idea

try with

```
const my_cool_function = function (){
  var y = window.innerHeight;
  var x = window.innerWidth;
   setThatDivTheSize({x, y});
}


window.onresize = my_cool_function;
```

Comment: out of interest, wh is the timer not a good idea?... i dont think your code gets the content of the iframe etc...

Comment: Is better to use an observer (like my example).  a timer is going to ask for the size even when is not necessary so it will affect in the performance...

Comment: Why out of interest BTW?

Comment: you can only get the iframe inner content size by using iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight ?